# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for fragment-different layout sizes

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

I'm trying to create my app support for different layouts (eg : layout-large-tvdpi).inside `layout-large-tvdpi` folder i have inserted tow layout (one layout for activity other for fragment).

when i run my app on Tablet activity layout showing fine.but when i move to fragment, app crashed and show me error`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views`.it's show error on `ButterKnife.bind(this,v)`

**This is my Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }
```

**This is My Fragment**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);        
        ButterKnife.bind(this,v);
        return v;
    }
```

**Log Cat**

[image]

**Fragment layout**

[image]

**Activity Layout**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Butterknife with Different Layouts for Phones and Tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206862/butterknife-with-different-layouts-for-phones-and-tablets)

Answer (score 2):

Check if your `@InjectViews` has correct type. I've used `ImageView` instead of `LinearLayout`. That might be your problem too.